# Problems using MySQL connector with Django 1.8

Tags: python, mysql, django

OS : CentOS 6.4
python version 3.4
django version 1.8

I had studies about django framework. Then, I going to move to storage part. At first of study, the default database is sqlite. So I was change some values in the settings.py file.

```
#DATABASES = {
#    'default': {
#        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
#        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
#    }
#}
DATABASES = {
    'default' : {
        'ENGINE' : 'mysql.connector.django',
        'NAME' : 'dj_mysql',
        'USER' : 'root',
        'PASSWORD' : '',
        'HOST' : '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT' :''
   }
}
```

I typed "python3 manage.my migrate", and I got these errors.

How can I overcome this situation. TT;
I'm struggling all day long.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're trying to use MySQL connector. The Django docs suggest that it [doesn't always support the latest version of Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/databases/#id10). [This bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76752) suggests that 2.1.3 supports Django 1.8, but users were still reporting problems with 2.1.3 on that bug report and in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33178945/django-mysql-connector-python-unknown-error).

The [Django docs recommend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers) that you use [mysqlclient](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient) to access MySQL databases with Django.

It's easy to install, for example with pip:

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Then all you need to do is change your databases setting to

```
DATABASES = {
    'default' : {
        'ENGINE' : 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You should update the mysql-connector-python, since the old version don't support Django 1.8 well. 
As the documentation of Django goes:

> MySQL Connector/Python is available from the download page. The Django >adapter is available in versions 1.1.X and later. It may not support the >most recent releases of Django.

Use the following command to update it from the MySQL website:

```
pip install http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-2.1.3.tar.gz
```