# Django MySql-Connector-Python - unknown error

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have been using Django for a website I run, I was recently tasked with moving the database to an external server. I've configured, installed MySql-Connector-Python, and configured both servers to talk to each other. I've since run into a strange error that I've seen others have issues with as well. I'm asking the question again as the other question are outdated. Django has changed what it supports since earlier this year in regards to external sql db servers. I'm currently running Django vs 1.8 on Debian, using python 2.7.9, I have my Sql DB on a separate server running CentOS using MySql Vs 5.6.

Here is the error I've been running into:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "../manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 351, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 325, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 41, in <module>
    class Permission(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 139, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 324, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 250, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 36, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 240, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 129, in load_backend
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'mysql.connector.django' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    u'base', u'mysql', u'oracle', u'postgresql_psycopg2', u'sqlite3'
Error was: cannot import name BaseDatabaseFeatures
```

Here is my settings.py:

```
import ldap
from django_auth_ldap.config import LDAPSearch, NestedActiveDirectoryGroupType
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'longrandomstringhere'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'WhiteBoard.base',
    'WhiteBoard.calendar',
    'WhiteBoard.grades',
    'WhiteBoard.django-auth-ldap-ad',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'WhiteBoard.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'WhiteBoard.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
    'NAME': 'dbname',
    'USER': 'dbuser',
    'PASSWORD': 'dbpass',
    'HOST': 'hostip',
    'PORT': 'port',
    }
}
```

I've done quite a bit of research on my own for this issue. The problem I run into is that the data is old, and will say things like "django doesn't support that yet" and that's changed. I can't find any clues or answers to the problem and it doesn't help that I'm on a short time frame.

Comment: Try `'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql'`

Comment: That's what I had previously before I used mysql-connector, but I will try it.

Comment: Change it to that produces an operationserror, "Can't connect to mysql server on "ip"."

Comment: The [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/databases/#id10) warn that mysql-connector may not support the latest version of Django. I would stick with MySQLdb or mysqlclient.

Comment: Strange..I have a working Django 1.8 project connected to a MySQL DB using [MySQL-python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5) as connector.

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31433762/cannot-import-name-basedatabasefeatures/31434116#31434116) - that's the same error as you are seeing.

Comment: @Leistungsabfall I'm not sure whether you were replying to me, but MySQL-python is the same as MySQLdb that I was referring to above.

Comment: Yes, but the reason I asked this question is because most question answers are outdated that answer notes this: This bug report suggests that 2.1.3 will support Django 1.8, but the download page shows that the latest current release is 2.0.4.   (The current version now is 2.1.3 not 2.0.4 as the answer sugest.)

Comment: If you are running 2.1.3 and you get the same error, then it suggests the problem isn't fixed. I think you'd be better off reporting a bug than asking on stack overflow. However, it's not clear why you need to use MySQL connector anyway. As I said before, there are other documented options that don't have these problems.